# Can I call add_compile_definitions in a toolchain file?

Tags: cmake, compilation, preprocessor

CMake provides variables such as `CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS_INIT` to allow you to set compiler flags in a toolchain file, but I don't know of an equivalent for setting preprocessor definitions. In fact, CMake doesn't really seem to distinguish between preprocessor flags an compiler flags.

What is the "correct", or "supported" way to set preprocessor macro definitions in a toolchain file? Is it acceptable to call `add_compile_definitions()`, should I include them in `CMAKE_C_FLAGS_INIT`, or does it go against some CMake philosophy to even set them in the toolchain file at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I call add_compile_definitions in a toolchain file?

Sure, it's equivalent to `string(APPEND CMAKE_C_FLAGS`.

> What is the "correct", or "supported" way to set preprocessor macro definitions in a toolchain file? Is it acceptable to call add_compile_definitions(), should I include them in CMAKE_C_FLAGS_INIT, or does it go against some CMake philosophy to even set them in the toolchain file at all?

It's best to set `*_INIT` variables from toolchain file, and also put there any definitions that you want. It's in the doc
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_FLAGS_INIT.html :

> This variable is meant to be set by a toolchain file

In practice, use:

```
string(APPEND CMAKE_${lang}_FLAGS_INIT " your_flag")
```

Examples from cmake:

```
$ cd /usr/share/cmake/Modules
$ grep _FLAGS_INIT -r .
./Compiler/ARMCC.cmake:  string(APPEND CMAKE_${lang}_FLAGS_INIT " ")
./Compiler/ARMClang.cmake:        string(APPEND CMAKE_${lang}_FLAGS_INIT " -march=${CMAKE_SYSTEM_ARCH}")
./Compiler/ARMClang.cmake:        string(APPEND CMAKE_${lang}_FLAGS_INIT " -mcpu=${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR}")
./Compiler/Absoft-Fortran.cmake:string(APPEND CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_INIT " ")
./Compiler/Bruce-C.cmake:string(APPEND CMAKE_C_FLAGS_INIT " -D__CLASSIC_C__")
./Compiler/Fujitsu.cmake:  string(APPEND CMAKE_${lang}_FLAGS_INIT " ")
./Platform/Android-Common.cmake:        string(APPEND CMAKE_${lang}_FLAGS_INIT " -stdlib=libstdc++")
./Platform/Android-Common.cmake:        string(APPEND CMAKE_${lang}_FLAGS_INIT " -stdlib=libc++")
./Platform/Android-Common.cmake:        string(APPEND CMAKE_${lang}_FLAGS_INIT " -stdlib=libc++")
./Platform/ARTOS-GNU-C.cmake:string(APPEND CMAKE_C_FLAGS_INIT " -DARTOS -Xp -+")

....
```

See the `Bruce-C.cmake` example above.

Comment: Hmm, so I guess my real question was "does CMake distinguish between preprocessor flags and compiler flags?", and it looks like the answer is "no". Thanks!

Comment: `does CMake distinguish between preprocessor flags and compiler flags?` Kind of, I believe if you add something twice to `add_compile_definitions` than it will be only once. I mean, the bottom line is, it's all compiler flags at the end. When you are writing a _toolchain_ file, you are specifically working with specific _toolchain_, not with abstractions.

Answer (score 0):

The toolchain files usually set up the environment and the flags needed for a specific target. So it is acceptable to add compile definitions required for such targets.